# How can one swap 2 columns in Microsoft Excel 365 if the sheet contains a sortable table?

Tags: office-365, sorting, excel-online

I have a  Microsoft Excel 365 file with a sheet containing a sortable table:

[image]

How can I swap 2 columns in this sheet (e.g., swap column `H` with column `I`)?

---

What I have tried unsuccessfully:

1. Select column `H` and drag-and-drop at the right of column `I`.
2. Select column `H`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd> at the right of column `I`.
3. Select column `H`, right-click on it, select cut, and try to paste it at the right of column `I`.

Attempt `1.` does nothing, while `2` and `3` gives me the error message:

> The operation cannot be completed for one of the following reasons:
>
> - A selection including cells both inside a table and below it cannot be copied and inserted into that table. Select cells outside the table and try inserting the data again.
> - You have attempted to fill data in a way not supported by the table.
>   Give Feedback

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/nt8f1j/how_can_one_swap_2_columns_in_microsoft_excel_365/h0qsfdo/) from [CHUD-HUNTER](https://www.reddit.com/user/CHUD-HUNTER):

> Click the header of the column you want to move. Press ctrl+shift+arrow_down to select the entire column (assuming there are no blanks). Grab the selection with the four-arrow cursor and drag it where you want to position it. When you are between the two columns you want to place it you will see the green outline turn into a large "I" shape. You can release the selection now.
>
> Based on your errors it seems like you are grabbing additional cells outside of your table range, so make sure you are only selecting your table range

Demo:

[image]